# Invisible energy in hadronic calorimeters

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

Hadronic calorimeters are more difficult to be built than electromagnetic ones because the cascade containment is much larger for former. There is also some "invisible" energy that is not contained in the detector (and therefore not measured). This invisible energy is carried by neutrons not detected in the calorimeters and other particles/processes. I would like to know if somebody could point me which particles might be carrying this invisible energies or in which processes it might be loss and not measured

Comment: Er ... just to clarify something, neutron behavior is a complex subject. In general *some* of their energy can be expected to appear in the device (though it may be highly quenched). The details depend on the energy of the neutron and the material/mechanism of the calorimeter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: cms]

This is the [CMS detector](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~korytov/research/layman_my_cms.html) at LHC in CERN. Note the tiny figure of a person on the right, to get an intuition of the size.

There are a number of detectors, in layers, like an onion,each designed for measuring the particles carrying energy and momentum, leaving from the center where the collision happens . To reconstruct the event all the detectors are necessary .

The tracker tracks individual particles in the detector, the crystal ECAL is designed to catch electromagnetic interactions, photons and electrons, photons just appear in the electromagnetic calorimeter, ECAL.

Electrons  will show as a track in the tracking but display an electromagnetic shower due to their small mass.

Heavier particles get through to the hadronic calorimeter, which is designed to absorb all energy from strongly interacting particles.

Muons are heavy and thus, though charged are not caught within the electromagnetic calorimeter, the same true for all long lived hadrons, protons, neutrons ,pi k mesons etc.

Muons interact electromagnetically and  weakly and are just a track in the hadronic calorimeter. They are caught in the much larger in mass and distances muon chambers, which are out of the kinematic range of hadrons,  where they leave a track.

Neutrinos can only be defined from the sum of energies and using energy and momentum conservation, as they interact only weakly and get out.

All these statements are qualified by widths and errors, which are estimated using monte carlo events.

[Here is how ideally](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2270046/plots) the various particles would leave their kinematic trace in the detector.

[image: event]

This plot shows the path of tracks leaving the interaction point that can be measured and four vectors assigned to tracks and jets.

Neutrons are contained and their energy measured in the calorimeter, see the plot.

The energy that leaves the detector leaves through the already measured
muons, which  go through if high energy enough, and not stopped through electromagnetic interactions.

Neutrinos go right through, and detected by using energy momentum conservation at the vertices. It is the only undetected energy that leaves the interaction region in principle.

Of course small angle beam scatters and some tracks go down the beam pipe undetected.

All these are modeled by monte carlo and corrections applied when necessary.

Secondary photons and generally interactions close to the outer limits  of the detector will also not be contained, but the four momenta should  have already been measured .

Comment: this is a generality that does not answer my question: where is the energy not contained in the detector going?

Comment: look at the muon going through, it just leaves. that is one other reason  why radiation dangers are high next to high energy experiments. Neutrinos ofcourse go through everything taking their energy with them.